# How can I download a song and add it the user's music library?

Tags: java, android

My Android app needs to download a MP3 track and add it to the user's media library.

I haven't found any good documentation on this so I was wondering if it is as simple as storing the MP3 in the Music directory? If so, what would be the location of the user's music directory?

Comment: how did you download song in your app? did you use any kind of library or what.. ? Really  need your help in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MediaScanner`

```
String mp3path = "Your MP3 file path";   
MediaScannerConnection msc = new MediaScannerConnection(yourcontext,
        new MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri){
                msc.disconnect();
            }
            @Override
            public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
                msc.scanFile(mp3path, null);
            }           
        });             
msc.connect();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just download the mp3 file just like any other file type.

you should find the directory to save by calling the Environment:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

and you can use the [scanFile method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to give a hint for the media scanner that the new music is there: