# android raw mp3 resource to native android media storage

Tags: android, mp3, local-storage, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to save mp3 resource embedded in my app to the android device. So that I can play it later in the default android media player.

I can get the inputstream of my resource no problem. But I can't get it to save to the device the default Java way.

And both these solutions didn't seem to work for me:

> [How can I download a song and add it the user's music library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280308/how-can-i-download-a-song-and-add-it-the-users-music-library)

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that your application has the appropriate permissions including `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Then you can copy the file from your resources to the android device. Here is an example code for **illustration purpose only**, change it as needed:

```
private void copyMp3() throws IOException{

// Open your mp3 file as the input stream
InputStream myInput = getAssets().open("your_file.mp3");

// Path to the output file on the device
String outFileName = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC),"your_file.mp3");

OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0 ){
   myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams => Better to have it in *final* block
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}
```

The media scanner should pick the file by itself (unless there is .nomedia file in that folder), but if you want to speed the process you can use the link you have referred to in your question.